# AWS lambda best practice question. Using a publish topic/sub to link 2 Lambdas in same microservice?

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices

We have several microservices (same account), that publish to topics in order to communicate with other services.

Within one service I have a lambda (`A`) in which I want to call another lambda (`B`), but I don't care what `B`'s response is. I just want to send the message to `B`, and it handles things from there, ensuring that I don't tie up the current thread on `A`.

No other services need to care about this event, which is why I thought a topic/sub, or creating a new service, does not fit this scenario. All I really care about is that the lambda `A` doesn't get tied up relying on what happens with `B`.

I am reluctant to just call `B` directly from `A`, and not `await` (i.e. without a callback), because it will increase the bundle size of `A`, when there is a small percentage of time that function `B` will actually be needed.

In a microservice architecture, what is the most correct approach here? Could I still create a topic for `A` that `B` will listen to, in the same microservice? Or is it best to  create a new 'service' anyways?

I just want to be careful to separate code so that the `A` lambda doesn't require the code/libs that `B` needs.

Comment: Added one comment that this is a Node environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally "a thing" to have a service use the pub/sub model internally. It's actually a good way of decoupling components and their execution. However, at this point the term "microservice" may no longer be accurate - not that it's well-defined to begin with.

The choice of whether a system's components should be strongly (`A` invokes `B`) or loosely (`A` publishes, which triggers `B`) coupled has a lot to do with what `A` and `B` are, and how they interact. For example:

1. Is `B` very complex, or very different from `A`? In your case, the answer to this is "no" - they're both lambdas, and lambdas' complexity is pretty self-limiting.
2. Is `B` expected to change frequently, in ways that will require changes to `A` if `A` takes a hard dependency on `B`?
3. Is `A` expected to change frequently, in ways that would make calling `B` directly inconvenient in the future?
4. Are there expected to someday be `C`, `D`, `E`, etc. triggering off of `A`, in addition to `B`?
5. Is there a one-to-many relationship between `A` and `B`, i.e. does one `A` trigger many `B`'s?

If your answer to some or all of the above is **yes**, loosely coupling via pub/sub is probably right for you. If your answer is *no* to most or all of them, pub/sub is *probably* overkill. I.e. if your answer is no, you're linking two simple components with few expected changes and little complexity.

---

A note on bundle size:

My opinion is that unless you are working with truly massive bundles, or building a system meant to be absolutely as lean as possible, *it probably doesn't matter*. [It won't even increase your cold-start time](https://read.acloud.guru/does-coding-language-memory-or-package-size-affect-cold-starts-of-aws-lambda-a15e26d12c76). I would recommend not worrying about it until it becomes a problem (which it is unlikely to, for most use-cases), rather than optimizing prematurely.

Comment: thank you for this explanation. exactly what I was looking to learn : )

Answer (score 1):

You have to call lambda inside another lambda using asynchronous invocation.

Here is explain properly how to call asynchronous lambda.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html

If you using python as base language for lambda this can help you.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke_async

In microservice architecture SNS ( topis ) is used for handshaking concept. Its means pubs -sub model. When A is job done then publish is that your work is done. Whoever is subscribe to A they will listen and start their job.

If you need to call lambda B when lambda A job is done then you SNS topics. But if need to call lambda B before process of lambda A is complete then you can call inside lambda also or can call SNS inside lambda raise SNS topics.

Comment: thanks for responding. so what you are saying is that it's perfectly normal to create Topics/Subs even in the same microservice ?